# Is there any good documentation on sysfs?

Tags: linux, documentation, sysfs

I'm looking for good documentation for sysfs; the man page is incomplete and even has one sentence that just stops half way through. I've found the Linux kernel documentation but that's a little bit too geared towards programmers as opposed to administration. If anyone can suggest a good source I'd be grateful.

Comment: What sentence are you referring to?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk it's the following excerpt from the description of the parameters/ directories within the subdirectories of /sys/module: "This  directory contains one file for each module parameter, with each file containing the value  of  the  corre‐sponding  parameter. Some  of these files are writable, allowing the"

Answer (score 6):

The only vaguely up-to-date documentation *is* the kernel documentation, [Documentation for `/proc/sys`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/). I’m (slowly) working my way through it, trying to ensure it’s complete, devoid of obsolete entries, and more understandable for administrators (after all, it’s part of the administrator’s guide); see [the `/proc/sys/kernel` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html) for example. I do realise that even the “improved” documentation is still hard to understand.

Relevant settings are also supposed to be mentioned in manpages where they’re relevant, *i.e.* close to the point of use.

If you have any specific questions, feel free to [ask them here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).